# Crash while sharing to Pintrest in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pinterest

I want to share a post on Pintrest( i.e. want to pin from my app). I have used its SDK using Cocoa Pod. I'm able to pin (share)  sometimes but sometimes while pinning it app crashes on random basis and getting nothing in crash log.

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong ? I'm adding the code snippet that i have used...I have used this link to install the SDK and followed this link. https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk

```
-(IBAction)pintrestButtonTapped
{
    @try
    {
        [PDKClient configureSharedInstanceWithAppId:@"4841203782190640720"];
        [[PDKClient sharedInstance] authenticateWithPermissions:@[PDKClientReadPublicPermissions,
                                                                  PDKClientWritePublicPermissions,
                                                                  PDKClientReadPrivatePermissions,
                                                                  PDKClientWritePrivatePermissions,
                                                                  PDKClientReadRelationshipsPermissions,
                                                                  PDKClientWriteRelationshipsPermissions]
                                                    withSuccess:^(PDKResponseObject *responseObject)
         {

             [PDKPin pinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.respectnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/cynja-app_store_share.jpg"]
                                link:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cynjaspace/id1050628761?ls=1&mt=8/"]
                  suggestedBoardName:@"CynzaSpace"
                                note:kSocialMediaSharingText
                         withSuccess:^
              {
                  NSLog(@"Successfully Pinned Up!!");
              }
                          andFailure:^(NSError *error)
              {
                  NSLog(@"UnSuccessfull");
              }];

         }
                                                     andFailure:^(NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"authentication failed: %@", error);
         }];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        // Print exception information
        NSLog( @"NSException caught" );
        NSLog( @"Name: %@", exception.name);
        NSLog( @"Reason: %@", exception.reason );
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add your code

Comment: I have the code snippet.

Comment: If you're getting no crash logs, how do you know the code you've quoted is the problem?

Comment: I have used the break point all over the methods for Pintrest but when app crashes no breakpoint is reached. Only app is closed.

Comment: @christopherdrum, this code is not the problem, this the code I have done for sharing, all the code is in its library.